# Promise.all vs m.sync

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

Are there any differences between the two functions?

I recently found a problem while using `Promise.all` within a controller.
The view would render before the `Promise.all` completion and I'd get empty variables inside the view.

So if I use one `m.request` to hit a single api then the view waits for it to complete. If I use many `m.request` wrapped in `Promise.all` then it does not wait! Am I doing something wrong?

Is this the correct behaviour? Is `m.sync` would behave somehow different, it seems to have the same signature as `Promise.all`?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The code with relevant bits

```
// Does two requests and wraps them in Promise.all
Table.show = (id, load) => {
  var header = m.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: cfg.apiurl(`/tables/${id}`),
  });
  var body = m.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: cfg.apiurl(`/tables/${id}`),
    data: {
      data: load
    }
  });
  return Promise.all([header, body]);
};

// The component
var ShowTable = {
  controller, view
};

// Controller function
function controller() {
  this.header = m.prop({});
  this.records = m.prop([]);
  this.pages = m.prop(0);

  var load = {
    filter: {},
    paging: {
      number: 1,
      size: 10
    }
  };

  var showTable = () => {
    Table.show(m.route.param("id"), load).then((res) => {
      this.header(res[0].data);
      this.records(res[1].data);
      this.pages(res[1].meta.pages);
    }, (res) => {
      popa();
    });
  };

  showTable();

}

// View function
function view(vm) {
  return m("div", [
    m("p", vm.header()),
    m("p", vm.records()),
    m("p", vm.pages()),
  ]);
}
```

**EDIT2**

Yes, `m.sync` works. But `Promise.all` does not.

Comment: Are you doing something wrong. Probably. Without code it's impossible to tell

Comment: If you show us your code, then we can likely tell you what you are doing wrong in your code.  If not, then not much we can do.

Comment: I hope that I am doing something wrong, otherwise I'll go crazy. Added the cut down code for you. It is too much to post all the bits so I trimmed it as much as I could preserving the point of the question.

Comment: if `m.sync` works correctly with the so-called *promises* that `m.request` returns and `Promise.all` does not, there's clearly some sort of issue with the so-called *promise* returned by `m.request` that `Promise.all` does not work well with. Failing any interesting console messages, I would recommend you use `m.sync` with `m.request` seeing as they come from the same library, they perhaps have a mutual understanding of the so-called *promises* they work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation landed me to [this page](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.computation.html). Redraw is done only for mithril's built-in functions, `Promise.all` is a native javascript function so no auto-redraw. You should either use `m.sync` or `m.startComputation/m.endComputation` in your `showTable` function. You can even return directly `[header, body]` without `Promise.all/m.sync`, they are both promises and mithril props so you can use/assign them to your viewmodel and when their value is populated, it should trigger a redraw in the view.

Anyway, if it still doesn't work, don't waste your time, just put `m.redraw()` in the then of `Promise.all`.